# How to count a total percentage for calculated measure in MDX (Mondrian)?

Tags: mdx, measure, mondrian, saiku

I have a problem which looked like a simple requirement ... it turned out it wasn't ... at least for me.
At the moment I feel like I've read half of the MDX internet ...
I'm using latest Saiku CE (Mondrian 4), and my simplified cube looks like this:

Dimensions:

- **Machine.Manufacturer**

Measures:

- **Measure.[Msg count]**
- **Measure.[Distinct machines]**
- **Measure.[Distinct days]**

Calculated measures:

- **Measure.[Msg xMxD]** which is basically: (Measure.[Msg count] / Measure.[Distinct machines] / Measure.[Distinct days]).
- **Measure.[Msg xMxd %]** which is: (Measure.[Msg xMxD] / SUM(Measure.[Msg xMxD], Machine.[Manufacturer].[All Manufacturers]))

What I want to accomplish is this table:

[image]

But as you've probably guessed, I have a problem with the Measure.[Msg xMxd %] measure ...
Because it is calculated on base of another calculated measure, the % calculation is done after the summing for a particular Manufacturer and I don't know how to overcome this.
The closest answer I found was this one: https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/160265-Calculate-members-in-mdx/
... but this concerns only one generated member as a sum of all manufacturers.

I've found also some resolutions based on Axis(...) functions but those are unavailable in Mondrian.

Do you have any ideas ?  Is there a possibility to generate a set of calculated members ? this would (at least theoretically) give me a possible to set solve order for all child members of [Machine].[Manufacturer]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you've tried SOLVE_ORDER with no success?

Comment: Hi @whyteq. It looks like I've managed to do this with SOLVE_ORDER ... but I have 2 other problems ... Saiku editor does not suppot SOLVE_ORDER, and secondly, I just can't write this in olap xml ... when I try, no error is reported by saiku, just new fields are not displayed in the table

Comment: also ... I don't know how to use SOLVE_ORDER with more than one hierarchy member